# Wordpress reset password button not working

Tags: password

I tried all the way but I didn't find the reason behind so that I can why this WordPress, woo commerce reset password button not working.I am using Spa Lab | Beauty Salon WordPress theme. I tried following way but not found a solution.

1. Uninstalling all plugin and checking one by one all plugin.
2. I also replace all woo commerce file with latest downloaded woo
   commerce.
3. I also replaced spalab theme all files with the new latest file but
   I still didn't understand what's the reason.

---

This is link where I am facing problem:- https://beautytree.ca/c/lost-password/

Answer (score -1):

The markup of your button is `<input disabled="" class="woocommerce-Button button" value="Reset Password" type="submit">` it shouldn't be disabled, removing the disabled attr doesn't seem to fix the problem, but I think that this button is "Decoration", and it is not associated with any ajax request, the theme default functionality for reset password seems to open the wp-login.php reset `http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-spalab/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword`

Answer (score -2):

If changed the URL may not allow any user to login. Try Deleting Cookies, or try in other browser. Or wait for some time may be around 30 min not more- because in  such cases to update word press may take long time.